# Loop through Json files and extract specific data

Tags: c#, json, dto

I have a bunch of Json files in storage where I can loop through to pick out a set list that meets my criteria. Even though the Json files have different data and structures, they all have 1 thing in common - A Metadata property with the structure like:

```
"meta": {
    "source": "user1",
    "createdDate": "2018-07-16T16:36:58.6471066+01:00",
    "recordCount": 12
},
```

I would like to extract the metadata of each file and store the results in a new DTO with the structure:

```
"data": [
{
    "source": "User1",
    "createdDate": "2018-07-16T16:36:58.6471066+01:00",
    "recordCount":12
},
    {
    "source": "User2",
    "createdDate": "2018-07-15T13:01:23.5611259+01:00",
    "recordCount":18
}
]
```

At the moment my code looks like this:

```
foreach (string s in objectType) //objectType is a simple string array for my file criteria
{
    var fileData = storage.GetS3(s, testOrg); //custom method to get file from storage, returns the json file contents using StreamReader. Returns null if no file found

    if (fileData != null) 
    {
        var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(fileData);

        //extract metadata from file to populate DTO

    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated. I am very much a newbie to c# in general so please go easy!

My DTO currently looks like the following but can be changed:

```
public class FileStatusResponse
{
    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public FileStatusDetail[] Data { get; set; }
}

public class FileStatusDetail
{
    [JsonProperty("source")]
    public string FileType { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("recordCount")]
    public string RecordCount { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("refreshDate")]
    public DateTime RefreshDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Since they all have different structures, instead of deserializing to an object, I'd use json.Parse() and access the fields directly. Here's documenation: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ParseJsonObject.htm

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to share one or two simple but complete and well-formed samples of the JSON you need to parse?  The JSON included in your question is just a fragment and so is not well-formed according to https://jsonlint.com/.  For instance, is the `"meta"` property always at the root level in the JSON?

Answer (score 0):

OK I seem to have sorted it with:

```
var fileStatusList = new List<FileStatusDetail>();
        var storage = new S3Manager();

        foreach (string s in objectType)
        {
            var fileData = storage.GetS3(s, organisationCode);

            if (fileData != null)
            {
                var parsedObject = JObject.Parse(fileData);
                var parsedJson = parsedObject["meta"].ToString();

                var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Metadata>(parsedJson);

                fileStatusList.Add(new FileStatusDetail
                {
                    source = s,
                    RecordCount = json.RecordCount,
                    RefreshDate = json.CreatedDate

                });

            }

        }
```

Thanks itsme86 for pointing me in the right direction